# Contabilizar los caracteres de la palabra repetida de la frase

Tags: javascript

La intención es contabilizar los caracteres de una palabra tantas veces se repita en la frase, pero al usar match ó includes lo que me da es el valor 1 de true no sé como puedo tratar los caracteres de la palabra.

```js
var message = "Esto es un ejemplo, y en este ejemplo contabilizaremos la palabra ejemplo que se repite 3 veces.";
console.log((message.match(/ejemplo/g) || []).length);
console.log("Ejemplo".length)
```

Pero no consigo sacar el total de los caracteres haber si me podéis echar una mano.

---

He logrado hacer el calculo, pero no considero que sea la manera más correcta de hacerlo pero si hasta el momento la más simple.

Si me podéis echar un cable de hacerlo más breve y correcto sería de agradecer.

```js
var message = "Esto es un ejemplo, y en este ejemplo contabilizaremos la palabra ejemplo que se repite 3 veces.";

console.log("Palabras repetidas");
console.log((message.match(/ejemplo/g)).length);
console.log("Caracteres Totales");
console.log((message.match(/ejemplo/g)+0).length-message.match(/ejemplo/g).length);
```

Comment: ¿Con esa frase cuál es el resultado que esperas y por qué? Por favor sé más específico.

Comment: Si quieres trabajar con match, este te lo deja en un string por comas, una forma es separarlo en un array y ahi calcular su longitud

Comment: @Gabitohh Esa frase es un ejemplo lo que espero es que me devuelva el valor total de los caracteres que es 21 que sería la palabra ejemplo que contiene 7 caracteres y como se repite 3 veces sería 21.

Comment: @AngelReynaTorrejon no intento que sea con match también probé con includes pero no logro sacar el total de los caracteres.

Comment: Hola como buscas palabras, te sugiero un algoritmo "charladito": debes eliminar puntos, comas y demás separadores luego hacer un split por los espacios para tener las palabras. Acto seguido construir un objeto al que se va a agregar cada palabra encontrada por primera vez como atributo con valor 1. Recorres el array de palabras devuelto por el split y pasas al objeto (contador) agregando atributos o incrementando los existentes.

Comment: He logrado hacerlo de manera simple pero no es la más correcta, pero es lo que buscaba si me pudieseis echar un cable en hacer más optimo el código os lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma simple sería:

```
var message = "Esto es un ejemplo, y en este ejemplo contabilizaremos la palabra ejemplo que se repite 3 veces.";
  var matchMsg = message.match(/ejemplo/g);
```

Este match te devuelve "ejemplo,ejemplo,ejemplo" como 1 solo string, por eso te responde la longitud como 1

```
var sMsg = Array.from(matchMsg);
```

con esto conviertes el string en un array

```
console.log(sMsg.length*7);
```

Y entonces solo calculas la longitud del array, y lo multiplicas por la longitud de la palabra. "21"

Answer (score 0):

En este caso podés transformar la frase en una array separado por palabras (tiene sus limitaciones). Lo haces con el método `split()` y le pasas un espacio `" "`, que va a ser la guía para tomar las palabras. Después separas en otro array los indices donde se encuentra esta palabra y esa cantidad de indices (`length`), la multiplicas por los caracteres de tu palabra.

```js
let frase = "esto es una frase frase frase";
let frasearr = frase.split(" ");
console.log(frasearr); //mira el array que se creo

let indice = [];
let elemento = 'ejemplo';
let idx = frasearr.indexOf(elemento);

while (idx != -1) {
    indice.push(idx);
    idx = frasearr.indexOf(elemento, idx + 1);
}
        
let cantidadCaracteres = elemento.length*indice.length;
console.log(cantidadCaracteres);
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si la frase tiene comas, puntos o simplemente no tiene espacios?